What is the topological interpretation of Euler's identity?

The picture is from the Wikipedia page of Euler's formula. I don't understand topology at all, but I'm curious about the reasoning behind this interpretation. May someone provide references that might help me understand the meaning behind this Commutative diagram?

$t\mapsto e^{it}$ maps $[0,2\pi)$ (as well as $[2\pi,4\pi), [4\pi,6\pi), \dots$) to $S^1$; points that are near to each other in $[0,2\pi)$ etc. get mapped to points that are near to each other in $S^1$; and it's a group homomorphism, meaning $t+s\mapsto e^{it}e^{is}$, where the group operation in $\mathbb R$ is addition and in $S^1$ is multiplication; and the quotient $\mathbb R/\tau\mathbb Z$ has the same structure as $S^1$

@J. W. Tanner I think that I understand all of your words but the last sentence, what is the "Structure" of unit circle? What is the definition of it? I know this might sound trivial to you, may you give some reference of it?

$S^1$ and $\mathbb R/\tau\mathbb Z$ are isomorphic as groups and they are homeomorphic, meaning they are essentially the same topologically; the unit circle is a group under multiplication, and it has a topology, which roughly speaking tells which points are close to each other
